# how to convert wav to text file on windows with python

Tags: speech-to-text, pypi, pocketsphinx

i used this command to install the library "pocketsphinx". I have python 3.5

```
pip install pocketsphinx
```

How can i convert wav file to text file on windows (command prompt)
 Can I get "what time to what time : what text/statement" from this library? If not, how can i get it?

(For example : 00 to 09 : I am going to the market , 10-14 : But why are you coming with me, .. )

Comment: check this wiki http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx

Comment: it does not work..  as i need to use visual studio as per link. I want to use python on windows only to convert

Comment: see this https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python